# Why does this work? Object references in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've finally been curious enough to find out why javascript does its voodoo magic to learn why not all object references are created equal.

Given the example:

```
var a, b, c, d;
a = 100; b = a;

c = {}; d = c;

b = 10; d.e = 'f';

console.log(a, b); // outputs 100, 10
console.log(c, d); // outputs object => e = 'f', object => e = 'f'
```

If all variables in javascript are objects, then what makes the use case with `c` and `d` cast explicitly as an `Object` so different than defining `a` and `b` as `Number`? Or, why will `c` and `d` be linked to one another, and not `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All variables in JavaScript are not objects. There are native types as well.

`c` and `d` are *not linked* to one another. They are pointing to the same object reference. If you were to reassign `d` to something else, it will not affect `c`.

```
var c = {};
var d = c;
d = { foo: "bar" };

c === d // false
```

However, if you were to modify the object being referenced by `c` or `d`, it will modify the same object since `c` and `d` are both referring to the same object as in your example.

Comment: That makes a LOT more sense seeing it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that the difference is with `b`, you're *reassigning the variable to a new object/value*, while with `d`, you're *modifying the existing object*.

Comment: So what you're saying then is, that (as Anurag pointed out) using a Native type will implicitly create a `new` object, whereas reassigning the object to another variable simply makes a reference-- unless the `new` keyword is explicitly used?

Comment: This is not strictly correct.  The values assigned to `a` and `b` are *not* objects.

Comment: @Buzzedword: Something like that.

Comment: @lawnsea: Hence why I changed it to "object/value" rather than just "object".

Comment: @Buzzedword @JAB - No.  See Anurag's explanation and my annotation of your code sample.  The `new` operator has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @JAB - Well, it's *not* an 'object/value'.  It's just a value.

Comment: @Anurag's makes much more sense now with a code sample. Thanks guys.

Comment: @lawnsea: But if it WERE an object, the result would be the same as it is in the given example, as shown in Anurag's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `a` that is assigned to `b` is a Number.  The value assigned from `c` to `d` is a reference to an Object.

```
var a, b, c, d;
a = 100; // a has value 100, a number
b = a; // b has value 100, a number

c = {}; // c has value p, a reference to some object P
d = c; // d has value p, a reference to P

b = 10; // b has value 10, a number
d.e = 'f'; // P.e has value 'f', a string
```